# Why don't upvotes to my answer give me reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, community-wiki, up-votes

I answered a question recently and it seems like upvotes don't contribute to my reputation.

I've edited the answer like 14 times so is it possible that my answer turned into a "community" answer and upvotes don't contribute to my reputation?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, after a certain number of edits by you and/or others the answer becomes community wiki and further upvotes don't contribute to your reputation points. This limit is in place to prevent gaming the system by bumping a question to the main page to get it some attention and consequently upvotes.

From *[What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740)*, "How does a post become a Community Wiki post?":

> Posts enter community wiki mode when ...
>
> The body of the post has been edited by at least five (5) different users.
>
> The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner.

Comment: ohhhh... that is lame! I kept making my answer better and better. Damn.

Comment: @Hristo, I agree... this has happened to me several times.  As a side-effect of combatting people who pump the system for rep, the system punishes perfectionists.

Comment: What's the rationale behind this?  Doesn't it punish people for improving their answers?